# Removed all occurences from file A from file B

Tags: bash, sed

I have two files: A and B.

Contents of A:

```
http://example.com/1
http://example.com/2
http://example.com/3
http://example.com/4
http://example.com/5
http://example.com/6
http://example.com/7
http://example.com/8
http://example.com/9
http://example.com/4
```

Contents from file B:

```
http://example.com/1
http://example.com/3
http://example.com/9
http://example.com/4
```

Now, I would like to remove all the occurences of the lines in file B from file A.

I have tried following:

```
for LINK in $(sort -u B);do sed -i -e 's/"$LINK"//g' A; echo "Removed $LINK";done
```

But it didn't do anything at all.

Comment: How critical is the use of `sed`?  Are you allowed to use `sed` to write your `sed` script?  Could `awk` be used?  And the `grep` solution you've been given is simpler than using either `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, it definitely doesn't have to be sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -vf` will be simpler for this:

```
grep -vxFf file2 file1

http://example.com/2
http://example.com/5
http://example.com/6
http://example.com/7
http://example.com/8
```

Comment: Do you need a `-x` option or something to ensure that `http://example.com/1` from file B doesn't delete `http://example.com/100` etc?

Comment: Definitely @JonathanLeffler, `-x` will surely be needed here. Thanks